# How to visualize functional composition?

Tags: functions

How do we interpret functional composition geometrically?

Let us consider two functions: $f(x) = x^2$ and $g(x) = 2x + 5$

Now, $f(x) + g(x)$ would be: $x^2 + 2x + 5$, the graph of which is:

[image: graph]

As you can see, at a particular point of $x$, the $y$ coordinate of the two seperate function adds up for the resulting function, and hence, it is very intuitive to understand that the resulting function is a representation of the two functions.

However, I am being unable to find any such relation for composition, the below is a graph of the function composition($f(g(x))$):

[image]

How do we even interpret the functional composition geometrically?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Choose a value of $x$, a read the corresponding $y=g(x)$. Mirror the point $(0,y)$ to $(y,0)$. Now read $f(y)=f(g(x))$.

[image]

Comment: mmm...... don't know how to put it, but, interpreting it in this way or actually the whole notion of functional composition is very un-intuitive

Comment: like why do we even map the value of y = g(x) onto the x -axis?

Comment: or why don't we map f(g(x)) onto a seperate axis of it's own?

Comment: @BeshalJaenal: you were asking for a geometric interpretation. Don't complain to get one.

Comment: what is the purpose for such a mapping technique?

Comment: well just the questions that follow

Comment: However, does answer the particular question

Comment: Look also here: MathStackExchange: A graphical approach to composition of functions and iteration problem. (https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/495550/a-graphical-approach-to-composition-of-functions-and-iteration-problem)

Comment: "or why don't we map f(g(x)) onto a seperate axis of it's own?" - No reason. In fact, putting f(g(x)) onto a separate axis of its own is a very good idea.